# PL/SQL Homework on school: create a procedure that will validate employee's date of birth and this procedure accepts date of birth as parameter

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Originally, the question was:

---

### This time you create a procedure called VAL_BDAY_PROC that will validate the employee’s date of birth. The procedure accepts the date of birth as a parameter. Then create a trigger called VALIDATE_BDAY_TRIG that invokes the VAL_BDAY_PROC. Test the trigger by inserting a new row to the EMPLOYEE table with an invalid birthday.

I tried to do it step-by-step since I am just a beginner in PL/SQL by creating the below procedure:

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VAL_BDAY_PROC (employee_dob DATE)
AS
  chck DATE;
BEGIN
  chck := TO_DATE(employee_dob, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DOB IS VALID');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DOB IS INVALID');  
END;
/

EXEC VAL_BDAY_PROC('12/11/2001');
```

---

After trying to execute the procedure, I got the below error message:

---

```
Error starting at line : 296 in command -
EXEC VAL_BDAY_PROC('12/11/2001')
Error report -
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 1
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

---

Your input is highly appreciated to complete this homework. (NOTE: I am currently using Oracle 11g ver 4.1.4)

Thank you.

Comment: try EXEC VAL_BDAY_PROC(to_date('12/11/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy')); Oracle is trying to do an implicit conversion of the string to a date but it is in the wrong format. Doing an explicit conversion with the format specified should resolve this.'

Comment: @ShaunPeterson - that pretty much negates the whole validation concept, right? That's not the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared the input parameter to be of DATE data type.

That defeats the purpose: you want to pass in a STRING (VARCHAR2) and within the procedure to validate that the string represents a valid date (in the specific format you are looking for).

So - change the data type of the `employee_dob` parameter to VARCHAR2.

**ADDED**: ... and to understand why you got that specific error: You presented '12/11/2001' as the input, but the procedure expected a DATE. Since you didn't wrap the string within TO_DATE, with the format model 'DD/MM/YYYY', Oracle tried to use your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which in most cases is 'DD-MON-YYYY' by default (with the month shown as NOV, for example). Since 11 is not in the format 'MON' (for MONth, not MONday), the conversion failed and you got that error message. Note that this happened BEFORE the procedure execution was even attempted, since it was not possible to pass a valid argument to it in the first place. This is why the error message is not the one in your error handling block, but the generic Oracle message for that error.

Comment: Thank you @mathguy for this. In addition to that, would it be possible to call this procedure above using a trigger function?

Comment: I have tried to create the below trigger: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VALIDATE_BDAY_TRIG
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE_T
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_dob  VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO 
EMPLOYEE_T (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, EmployeeCity, EmployeeState, EmployeeZip, EmployeeBirthDate, EmployeeDateHired, EmployeeSupervisor)
VALUES (000, 'TESS', 'africa', 'kenya', 'NO', 11285, TO_DATE('05/13/1950', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06/27/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 455789);
v_dob := VAL_BDAY_PROC(:new.employeebirthdate);
END;

Comment: And run by EXEC VALIDATE_BDAY_TRIG;
But got the following error message: 
Error(2,10): PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
Error(7,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(7,10): PLS-00222: no function with name 'VAL_BDAY_PROC' exists in this scope

Comment: @Raymond - You cannot execute a trigger with the EXEC command, where did you get that idea? I hope not from your instructor or textbook!

Comment: @Raymond - actually the homework is very explicit: test the trigger by inserting a new row in the table - not by running it with an EXEC wrapper.

Comment: I tried to run with trigger only and got the Error(7,10): PLS-00222: no function with name 'VAL_BDAY_PROC' exists in this scope. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: @Raymond - OK... reading through your comments. You are trying to `v_dob := VAL_BDAY_PROC(....)` That can't work; `VAL_BDAY_PROC` is a procedure, it does not return a value. You need to go back and read again about what procedures do and how to call them.

Answer (score 0):

try to change TO_DATE  Format as 'DD-MON-YYYY'

```
YOUR CODE SHOULD BE :
     chck := TO_DATE(employee_dob, 'DD-MON-YYYY');

FINALLY:
EXEC VAL_BDAY_PROC('12-MON-2001')
```

EXCEPTION :
    TRY TO GET EXACT ERROR USING `'SQLERRM'`    SO THAT YOU WILL KNOW HOW TO HANDLE THE ERROR IN FUTURE!!!

Comment: The problem is in another place, see answer of mathguy.

Comment: try to understand my solution!! myself gave some other solution to solve it. j

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't work. Run (for example) `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';` and your "solution" will crush. Do you know, why?

Comment: buddy... your saying about the solution in rounded things. tht guys is beginner in pLSQL so handling exception is best things to do for his future ... so try to teach beginner level to beginners. even though ur master of anything.